# Dynamically add items to Magnific Popup gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

Is there any way to dynamically add gallery items in [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) that is already open? (or update the current item). Can't find anything about in in [plugin docs](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
// get instance (after popup was opened)
var mfp = $.magnificPopup.instance;

// modify the items array (push/remove/edit)
mfp.items.push({
    src: "some-image.jpg"
});

// call update method to refresh counters (if required)
mfp.updateItemHTML();
```

Regarding to what to put in `items` array, refer to documentation - http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#from-the-items-option

Comment: Is it possible to update/reinit items from html items when they are updated (e.g. images added)?